Reports stopped Showing Records after Civi Upgrade
I recently upgraded CiviCRM from 5.53.0 to 5.79.0. Since then, most of the reports have stopped showing records. For instance, I am posting the SQL Developer query of the Membership Summary Report below. Strangely, I found that it is accessing temporary tables that do not exist in the database.
I have another instance with the same version of CiviCRM installed. I checked there and found that it is not accessing temporary tables and is working fine. By the way, that server was not upgraded manually but had version 5.79.0 directly installed during the setup. Please help resolve this issue.
TIA.

Class used: CRM_Report_Form_Member_Summary

SQL Modes: ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS COUNT( DISTINCT membership_civireport.id ) as civicrm_membership_member_count, DATE_SUB(membership_civireport.join_date, INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(membership_civireport.join_date)-1) DAY) as civicrm_membership_join_date_start, MONTH(membership_civireport.join_date) AS civicrm_membership_join_date_subtotal, MONTHNAME(membership_civireport.join_date) AS civicrm_membership_join_date_interval, membership_civireport.membership_type_id as civicrm_membership_membership_type_id, contact_civireport.contact_type as civicrm_contact_contact_type, contribution_civireport.currency as civicrm_contribution_currency  
        

FROM  civicrm_membership membership_civireport

              
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact contact_civireport ON ( membership_civireport.contact_id = contact_civireport.id )

              
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_membership_status
                        ON (membership_civireport.status_id = civicrm_membership_status.id  )
              
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_membership_payment payment
                        ON ( membership_civireport.id = payment.membership_id )
              
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_contribution contribution_civireport
                         ON payment.contribution_id = contribution_civireport.id 

WHERE membership_civireport.is_test = 0 AND
                              contact_civireport.is_deleted = 0 AND ( membership_civireport.owner_membership_id IS NULL ) AND ((`membership_civireport`.`membership_type_id` IN (1,2,3,4))) AND ((`contribution_civireport`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT id 

FROM civicrm_contribution_financial_type_temp_1))) AND (`contribution_civireport`.`financial_type_id` IS NULL OR ((`contribution_civireport`.`financial_type_id` IN (7,3,17,20,1,4,12,11,14,13,15,10,6,8,2,19,16,5,9,18))))  

GROUP BY YEAR(membership_civireport.join_date), MONTH(membership_civireport.join_date), membership_civireport.membership_type_id  WITH ROLLUP     

LIMIT 0, 50


Looking at the SQL query I'm not seeing any temporary tables being accessed?

It seems the table civicrm_contribution_financial_type_temp_1 is a temporary one as per the naming

Ah yes, are these standard reports or have they been modified in anyway?

No, I'm directly using the templates with no modifications. Also tried different filters but no luck

Are all reports effected or only some? And are you on Drupal or Wordpress?

I faced the issue for multiple reports especially related to membership. btw I'm running on wordpress

An extension was causing the issue. I disabled it, and it is working fine now.


Can you share a bit more? Was the extension overriding the reports?

Report queries are affected by the extension, once I disabled it the temporary tables are not appeared again in the query

Just putting the name of extension in as text as may help others when searching: Access Control by Financial Type for Reports - https://civicrm.org/extensions/access-control-by-financial-type-for-reports

Thanks Both, useful to know
